# wireless networking

Tags: 11.10

I want to connect to the internet through my ipod by creating a wireless network on my laptop. I have a 3G connection dongle for internet. how can I link the two devices so that I can access internet on both the devices simultaneously.I am using Ubuntu 11.10 at present.

Answer (score 0):

See this -- [Mobile broadband sharing over adhoc wireless](https://askubuntu.com/questions/104264/mobile-broadband-sharing-over-adhoc-wireless)

- Adhoc mode :

In this mode , you need to set up your network always. For support of your card and mode details please refer.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Adhoc

In 12.04, I think there is button to create wireless network in one go. But you will need DHCP server. Try with static IP.

---

- Setup A wifi access point:

This is one time setup, but complex.

For running your laptop as an access point, this is only possible if your wireless adapter supports going into the `master mode`. If it does not support this, you're totally out of luck.

How to test `master mode` and configure access point

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/MasterMode

Helpful threads to setup wireless access point

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessAccessPoint

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=376283

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1663788